# Completion Of 'XML Doc Comment' in ReSharper C++

Tags: c++, resharper

I've using ReSharper for C# many years an now using the C++ version. But when I type /// above any method no completion happening. I would expect an XML doc comment of the method.

Is this not available in ReSharper C++ or do I have to enable it somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not available in ReSharper C++ 2016.1.

R++ 2016.2, due out next week, will provide a document context action, configurable using a live template. It will default to generating doxygen-style documentation, but the template can also be changed to generate XML doc.

Comment: Update: ReSharper 2016.2 is out now.

Comment: Worked perfectly and stopped now when I press 3 times / nothing happens. Can you help me where I have to look in the settings or how I can reset all settings (I never changed anything). Thanks.

Comment: It does not happen on ///, you have to invoke a context action on the symbol to insert the comment (hit Alt+Enter on a function name and select 'Document'). The reason for that is it might take significant time to parse a C++ file, so R++ should not block the UI while waiting for the parse to finish when /// is detected.

Comment: Ah. Okay. Thank you!